# Python Selenium Element not found and Not Intractable

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to **scrape** from the `moneycontrol.com`. When I tried to **send value in the search box** I keep getting the same error in except block as "Element not Found".
I tried using **XPath id** as well as using the **full XPath** but in both cases, it doesn't work.

**WITHOUT MAXIMIZING THE WINDOW**

**XPath id** - `//*[@id="search_str"]`
**Full XPath** - `/html/body/div[1]/header/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/input[5]`

Attaching the full code below:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def search_stock():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        r'./chromedriver')
    driver.get('https://www.moneycontrol.com/')
    time.sleep(5)
    search_icon = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="fixedheader"]/div[4]/span')
    search_icon.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        search_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search_str"]')
        print("Element is visible? " + str(search_box.is_displayed()))
        time.sleep(10)
        if search_box.is_displayed():
            search_box.send_keys('Zomato')
            search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Element not found")
    driver.close()

search_stock()
```

Sometimes, it started working but most of the time it throwing exceptions and errors. Struggling since 3 days but none of the solutions working.

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking on `search_box` and only after that sending text there.

```
search_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//form[@id="form_topsearch"]//input[@id="search_str"]')
search_box.click()
time.sleep(0.1)
search_box.send_keys('Zomato')
search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Additionally I would advise you using explicit waits of expected conditions instead of hardcoded sleeps.
With it your code will be faster and more reliable.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def search_stock():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'./chromedriver')
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    driver.get('https://www.moneycontrol.com/')

    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="fixedheader"]/div[4]/span')).click()

    search_box =  wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//form[@id="form_topsearch"]//input[@id="search_str"]')))
    search_box.send_keys('Zomato')
    search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    #I'm not sure you should close the driver immediately after involving searching....
    #driver.close()

search_stock()
```

**UPD**
Let's try this

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


def search_stock():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'./chromedriver')
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    actions = ActionChains(driver)

    driver.get('https://www.moneycontrol.com/')

    search_icon = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="fixedheader"]/div[4]/span')).click()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", search_icon)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", search_icon)

    search_box =  wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//form[@id="form_topsearch"]//input[@id="search_str"]')))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", search_icon)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", search_icon)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    search_box.send_keys('Zomato')
    search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    #I'm not sure you should close the driver immediately after involving searching....
    #driver.close()

search_stock()
```

If the above solution is still not working instead of

```
actions.move_to_element(search_box).click().perform()
```

try

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", search_box)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the super fast answer. I'm getting TimeOutException at search_box. It's not becoming clickable,

Comment: But the search_icon does?

Comment: Yes, search_icon clicking well. But this search_box =  wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//form[@id="form_topsearch"]//input[@id="search_str"]'))) still not interactable.

Comment: No. I even have no python installed on my computer :) But don't worry,  we will find the solution

Comment: Thank you @Prophet, I'm struggling with this small thing and not able to find the exact way to solve this.

Comment: Please see if the updated answer works. It's strange to me why the previous solution didn't work

Comment: I tried both methods, and getting ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable every time.

Comment: I see... I changed some actions to JavaScript. Hope this will work.

Comment: Now getting this, JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null :(

Comment: Well, I see your conversation with cruisepandey. Our efforts should 1000% work in normal environments. Since you are working inside something strange it's hard to understand wat happens there and why things are not working. Need to run and debug inside that environment...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235286/discussion-between-prophet-and-prateek).

Answer (score 0):

web scraping like that seems quite inefficient it is prob better to use requests and bs4.  However if you want to do it like this you could try using action chains. [found here](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html) Or you can do `driver.get('https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/consumer-food/zomato/Z')` from the start instead of typing it in.

Comment: Hey, I have tons of other stock items to scrap and I don't know the types of stock like here you can see "consumer-food" and follow by zomato.  And there are most of the stock might be not available on moneycontrol and using search option I'm handling error well.

Comment: @Prateek can you try using action chains then, I have had great success using that to click hard to click elements and in your case typing

Comment: Hey, let me check action chains. I don't know much about it. but let me try.

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna try the below code :

```
def search_stock():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'./chromedriver')
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.get('https://www.moneycontrol.com/')
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    time.sleep(5)
    try:
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id='search_str']")))).perform()
        search_box = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id='search_str']")))
        print("Element is visible? ", search_box.is_displayed())
        time.sleep(10)
        if search_box.is_displayed():
            search_box.send_keys('Zomato')
            search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Element not found")
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: Hey @cruisepandey, I'm getting TimeOutException search_box = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id='search_str']"))) and I don't have to maximize the window. With maximized window, able to search.

Comment: Are you sure ? it's working all okay in my machine, I know it would take some time to execute, run it and do not do any manual intervention

Comment: @Prateek : I don't have to maximize the window. With maximized window, able to search. - I do not understand that, Why don't you need that ? if we don't maximize the screen we will get that error for sure, cause element won't be in Selenium view port.

Comment: Actually, the EC2 instance of AWS not able to maximize the size I want, and that's why I'm trying without maximizing.

Comment: With maximization, it working well on my machine too.

Comment: okay, figured that out, You can use the updated code above, I have used Actions chain for this matter, works in my local

Comment: With maximize window it is working well in my machine too. But when I tried same code in EC2 instance, getting   File "C:\Scripts\Scheduled\MoneyControl\stock_action.py", line 19, in search_stock
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
  File "C:\Users\prateek.rai\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:  this error

Comment: Hmm.. not sure about EC2, it did work in my local without windows maximize.

Comment: That's why I exactly asked this ques. The main issue of that maximize window.

Comment: You should have mentioned that in your question at first place, it's a specific issue only occurs to you. I believe even @Prophet would be able to run it successfully.